# JFace ProgressMonitorDialog not showing progress bar if fork is false

Tags: eclipse, jface

I have a progress monitor dialog from jface ( Indeterminate progress ), if I set the fork as false i.e. the dialog is run in main GUI thread, my monitor won't show progress , the progress bar is just blank. 
I want to run the dialog in main GUI, but still want to show progress bar. How can I do it?

Exact problem is like : I start progress monitor then make a server call, then after server call returns ; in a separate thread, I do the processing from results of server call - this is again a UI Thread and involves dialogs, views etc. The problem is the progress monitor in the first thread that started before server call ( the server call is in a serparate thread ) is hidden behind the dialogs / views in second runnable for processing the server results

Answer (score 2):

If you're busy in the UI thread, there's no time for the progress dialog itself to redraw. The fork parameter of [the run method](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/ProgressMonitorDialog.html#run(boolean,%20boolean,%20org.eclipse.jface.operation.IRunnableWithProgress)) doesn't control whether the *dialog* runs in the UI thread, it always must, it controls whether your `IRunnableWithProgress` does. That's why it's recommended you pass in `true`.

Comment: In windows, you could end up with a window that is "not responding" if you specify false for the fork parameter.  Especially if you have along running process that doesn't update the progress.

Comment: Yes I understand, but my problem is like : I start progress monitor then make a server call, then after server call returns ; in a separate thread, I do the processing from results of server call - this is again a UI Thread and involves dialogs, views etc. The problem is the progress monitor in the first thread that started before server call ( the server call is in a serparate thread ) is hidden behind the dialogs / views in second runnable for processing the server results.

Comment: You should probably refactor all of this into a single runnable, or something that can delegate the work and not open dialogs of its own. Then use multiple SubMonitors within the intiial/main dialog's progress monitor. http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/SubMonitor.html .